# Controls appearing beneath GridSplitter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a GridSplitter in my app and the ListView control is always appearing beneath the Splitter. How do I make the ListView control fit *within* the bounds of the left part of the GridSplitter without forcing a fixed-width on the ListView?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Margin="0, 25, 0, 22">
        <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <TextBlock Text="sd" />
                    </ListViewItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

    <GridSplitter Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFCFE5F0" Margin="0, 25, 0, 22" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in the columns

```
<Grid Margin="0, 25, 0, 22" Grid.Column = 0 
<GridSplitter Grid.Column = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `GridSplitter` into the appropriate column. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <TextBlock Text="sd" />
                    </ListViewItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFCFE5F0" Margin="0, 25, 0, 22" />
</Grid>
```